# Warren and it's investments

Tags: starting-out-investing

Hi guys I'm like of course many others getting started on investments. Current college student, reading the intelligent investor.

**My question is:** how can I learn where to get started? I'm overflowed with information but they all teach you about concepts. For example, I was reading about bonds, but, let's say I wanted to invest 5% in them, where do O do it?? I trid nadex and that's very volatile, not what I'm looking for, and it doesn't have a long term, it goes by minutes or hours. So where do warren buffet invest that he can put the money and grow over the years and it's not like a 5 minutes binary? (Don't confuse it tho, I'm not asking for warren's formula lol)
I don't know if I explain myself correctly, let's say I also want to buy a share of a company X, where do I buy it? For how long can I have it, etc?

Thank you

Comment: Sports arbitrage betting is good low risk investment that you can do with low capital (which I assume is the case given the question you asked) see https://betslayer.com/blog/what-is-sports-arbitrage-betting

Answer (score 0):

If I were in your shoes I would concentrate now on investing in yourself.  Your greatest wealth building tool is your income.  Going to school is great, make sure you can finish.  Also is there additional coursework you can obtain that might help boost your salary?  I would look for course in the following areas that might be outside your core competency:

- Software development
- Internet research methods
- Managerial accounting
- Excel/Powerpoint
- Business/Technical writing
- Project management
- Public speaking

After that I would concentrate on some books that will help you in your journey.  However, I would not start investing until you have a well paying full time job:

- Bogle on Mutual Funds
- The Warren Buffet Way

That will get you started.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. You are on the full time job, I didn't think about it that way. So what do I do with the spare money? I don't want to waste it on gadgets

Comment: I'm studying software development (C.S)

Comment: A savings account will serve you best for now stock pile money to make sure you get through school.  Read the two book I recommend.  Look into taking project management and managerial accounting.